# Use options set on apache camel direct endpoint

Tags: apache, apache-camel

I am building a routing slip bean and want to apart from the dynamic routing also to send a parameter to the endpoints of the recipients list.

I wish to use something like "direct:test?param=value", where param and value are set inside the routing slip POJO

From what I understand from the direct component, a single "direct:test" endpoint will receive all the routed exchanges, however I need a way to read the param send from the routing slip

How can I use this param to the endpoint which receives the exchange? Is it a property of the exchange?

Comment: after some testing, setting params on a direct endpoint such as "direct:test?para=value" does not seem to work as direct does not know how to handle those params, from what I understand a custom endpoint is needed.

Answer (score 2):

Pan,

I'd use the [header](http://camel.apache.org/header.html) functionality of camel.  It's quite versatile and you can handle it using [predicates](http://camel.apache.org/predicate.html) for some nice DSL or spring control, or in a [bean](http://camel.apache.org/bean-language.html)/[processor](http://camel.apache.org/processor.html) by doing myExchange.getIn().getHeader("foo").

Comment: Thanks for the response. I need to mulitcast an incoming XML message to various routes depending on the incoming message variables. I was hoping to "cut-down" some routes which actually use header and predicates to parametrized the copied exchange of the multicast by using a Routing Slip. However If I can't pass parameter to the target endpoint of the routing slip this is not possible.