# Apache Camel : Sending parameters to direct

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

Planning to call same direct mutiple times using multicast to acheive parallelism and in need to send a parameter to the endpoint.

I wish to use something like "direct:test?param=value1", "direct:test?param=value2" where param and value are set to call another dynamic route.

example : toD(direct:${xxxx.param})

Please share inputs on this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use options set on apache camel direct endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14257499/use-options-set-on-apache-camel-direct-endpoint)

Comment: thanks for your input on this. But i Could't see any example over the link and routing me to camel www, could you please provide me syntax for better understanding, Many Thanks.

Comment: In short, Camel's [DirectComponent](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/main/docs/direct-component.adoc) will prevent you from providing parameters it does not support. The next best thing would be to add the values you need to pass to the headers of the message you pass along within the exchange. You can use `.setHeader("param", constant("value1"))` or a `simple(...)` construct instead the `constant` before performing your `toD(...)` i.e.